# How to resolve Navigation bar issue as attached in Image?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, statusbar

Recently i am come across with one issue in `UINavigationBar`.
Please mention attached image so you can identify the issue.

[image]

Status bar is also not appearing in screen

What should i do to resolve it?

**UPDATE****

By setting SetTranslucent = NO property it creates below issue as attached in image.

[image]

Comment: [myNavigationBar setTranslucent:NO]; -- in viewDidLoad

Comment: @Mrunal, That navigation bar issue only course when i DO present one view controller and then dismiss and come to my original controller.

Answer (score 0):

copy the below line and paste it in your `viewDidLoad` method

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

or select your `viewController` in Storyboard and Select the 'Attribute Inspector' in right side pane and uncheck the 'Adjust Scroll View Insets' checkbox under Layout section.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have salved my issue .

I Issue is i am displaying `Status Bar` in my Current View Controller and then When i presenting `Modal View Controller` `Status Bar` is hide there.

simply ny hide Status bar in Modal View Controller` my issue is salved.

Thanks.